# React Native Scrollview do not have scroll end option

Tags: react-native

Hello i'm beginner of react native.
I'm facing some problems with scrollview (I want load more function with scrollview)
I already coded design with react native.
Now i read react native scroll view have no scroll end event but they recommend FlatList.
If I use FlatList My Design not smoothly work .
Please Help me.
Thanks you very much.

Comment: Maybe there was some mistake and you read about "ScrollView do not have scrollToIndex. Use instead FlatList."?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';

const ScreenComponent = (props) => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef();
  return (
    <ScrollView
      ref={scrollViewRef}
      onContentSizeChange={() => scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
    />
  );
};
```

using scrollViewRef you can go to end of scrollview..